# I cant display html

Tags: c++, qt

so, I was trying to display an html to textbrowser when I press the button and I get a message that says: unable to find string literal operator 'operator""https' with 'const char [38]', 'unsigned int' arguments

Here is my code

```
       #include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include <QFile>
#include <QTextStream>
#include <QMessageBox>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <qlayoutitem>
#include <QString>
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QDir>
#include <QtCore>
#include <QFileDialog>
#include <QDesktopServices>


using namespace std;

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}




void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{

        ui->textBrowser->setText("<html><body><iframe src=\"https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4k6aYtTLhHbamxJNGNqTDZqWHM/preview\" width=\"640\" height=\"480\"></iframe></body></html>");


}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_4_clicked()
{
    QString link = "https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSdazoZx2TpWblMfrvZGJwgvPl8qz4Ftxb0aOkht2bfUSklXcw/viewform";
    QDesktopServices::openUrl(QUrl(link));

}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_3_clicked()
{
    QString link = "https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSdazoZx2TpWblMfrvZGJwgvPl8qz4Ftxb0aOkht2bfUSklXcw/viewform";
    QDesktopServices::openUrl(QUrl(link));

}


void MainWindow::on_pushButton_5_clicked()
{
    QString link = "https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSdazoZx2TpWblMfrvZGJwgvPl8qz4Ftxb0aOkht2bfUSklXcw/viewform";
    QDesktopServices::openUrl(QUrl(link));

}
```

Comment: u have to escape the quotes in the string

Comment: wait.. where which line?

Comment: You have only one string in your code, so..

Comment: lol - no thats not going to happen, u need to read basic book on c++ programming, see section on string literals

Comment: @pm100 I know c++ but not QT.

Answer (score 1):

escape the quotes

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
   ui->textBrowser->setText("<html><body><iframe src=\"MY GOOGLE DRIVE EMBED LINK\" width=\"640\" height=\"480\"></iframe></body></html>");


}
```

i also note that the code you posted is not the code that failed - please try to post the real code

Comment: Doesnt work :(( my app opens up but when I press to load the file its just blank.

Comment: yes it does work, now you have a different issue. Ask a new question

Comment: the rest that I havent posted is buttons that when I press them opens a link on default browser which works perfectly. yea but I dont know what is the problem, can you help? I can share screen on skype.

Comment: I tried to paste it but it says thats its too long. should I create a new post?

Comment: @Lambros Yes and no. New question, but reduce your over-long code to the minimum possible code that causes your problem. Odds are good that reducing your code to the minimum will show you exactly where the bug is and how to fix it. If not, you will have the [mcve] required by all "Help fix my code" questions.

Comment: @pm100 I cant post for a week, I hav e edited the code, help me please :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
ui->textBrowser->setText("<html><body><iframe src="MY GOOGLE DRIVE EMBED LINK" width="640" height="480"></iframe></body></html>");
```

There are 2 solutions:

1) Escape inner double quotes:

```
ui->textBrowser->setText("<html><body><iframe src=\"MY GOOGLE DRIVE EMBED LINK\" width=\"640\" height=\"480\"></iframe></body></html>");
```

2) Replace inner double quotes with single quotes:

```
ui->textBrowser->setText("<html><body><iframe src='MY GOOGLE DRIVE EMBED LINK' width='640' height='480'></iframe></body></html>");
```

Comment: I've tried it and there is no problem anymore but when I press to get list it simply doesnt show anything. can you help through skype?

Comment: Or just use a raw string literal - http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal